# Serana fighting Paarthurnax

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just completed the quest Alduin's Bane. Serana was my follower at the time.

My problem is that during the fight with Alduin, Paarthurnax must have accidentally damaged Serana or vice versa, and now that the fight is over they are fighting each other.

I am playing on PC so I will be able to use console commands.

How should I go about fixing this? I tried selecting Serana and typing 'resetai' and 'disable'/'enable' but she continues attacking Paarthurnax.

Update: I temporarily fixed the issue by reducing Serana's health to 0 and then fast travelling elsewhere. I wasn't able to see what would happen when she got back up but I will leave this question up anyway as I suspect that there would be a cleaner solution using console commands.

Comment: try using the command stopcombat on them.

Comment: After you fast traveled, did Serana follow you? If so, you can just wait up to 30 days and your problem is fixed without having to risk the console.

Comment: She did follow me as I fast travelled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select Serana and use the `stopcombat`command. Do the same to Paarthurnax. Be sure to not leave the console between running both commands.

This will remove their aggression state which should (hopefully) persist until their next altercation.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a save from just before the battle occurs, then reload to it. while it isnt ideal, it means you can replay through it and try to avoid this bug occuring again.

this is why you always save before you do anything in skyrim! its a buggy game so its always better to be safe than sorry

Answer (score 0):

If you are playing on PS3, run down the mountain until Paarthurnax's health bar disappears, then fast travel away. Even if Serena is fighting, the fast travel will stop her. If you still need to kill him, have Serena wait BELOW the fast travel line. If not, she is an eager fighter and will join in.

Answer (score -2):

Just wait until paarturnax defeats serana, then she shall attain drem, and will be peacible. Then simply interact with paartunax and say krosis, and you may resume your tiinvaak. Worst case scenario, you cast yourself back to a previous tiid, from a previous save.

Comment: Care to repeat that in the common tongue?

Comment: Instructions unclear, Paarthurnax and Serana are now dead.